# Insert and retrieve data from database to TreeView control in C# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I am working with a project, in which I have a task that Names represents with hierarchy in a treeview control.

That means I must able to add the parent and child nodes to treeview and when I click <kbd>Save</kbd> button all the nodes should be stored in database.

My typical task is, if I retrieve the data, all the parent and child node should retrieved and added to the treeview control as I inserted hierarchy only.

Comment: Naresh: we help answering questions, not perform entire tasks for you. You should atleast try it yourself and if you have questions, add what you tried including source code.

Answer (score 0):

Go through following links it might get you started to come with real question.

http://msmvps.com/blogs/deborahk/archive/2009/11/09/populating-a-treeview-control-from-a-list.aspx

http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/net30/article.php/c15887/Updating-a-Database-from-WinForms-Controls-Old-School.htm